# User needs to re-authenticate with Azure AD B2C after the user closes and reopens the browser

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an Angular front end application which is using Azure AD B2C custom policies(Home Realm Discovery) to authenticate the federated AAD user.
After I login to the application with federated Azure AD tenant user, close this tab(without logout) then open a new tab, access application and login, this user can be automatically sign in. This is the expected behavior as SSO feature.

But if I close the browser and reopen the browser, when try to login it asks me to input user name, seems the session is lost and the user need to re-authenticate.

I saw below documentation on Microsoft website:

> The Keep me signed-in feature extends the session life time through
> the use of a persistent cookie. The session remains active after the
> user closes and reopens the browser. The session is revoked only when
> a user signs out. **The Keep me signed-in feature only applies to
> sign-in with local accounts**.

I was wondering is there a way to use the persistent cookie for Azure AD B2C(federated Azure AD tenant user)? How can I keep the session active after the user closes and reopens the browser?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According Microsoft doc.

> You can enable Keep Me Signed In (KMSI) functionality for users of
> your web and native applications that have local accounts in your
> Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) directory. This feature
> grants access to users returning to your application without prompting
> them to reenter their username and password. This access is revoked
> when a user signs out.

And ***Prerequisites***.

> An Azure AD B2C tenant that is configured to allow local account
> sign-in. KMSI is unsupported for external identity provider accounts.

So,at present, there is no way to use the persistent cookie for Azure AD B2C(federated Azure AD tenant user).

For more information,please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in).